# jQuerys' hover causes div to flicker

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I'm working on a 'portfolio' which shows pictures of different things. When the end-user hovers over one of those pictures, I want a 'caption' to fade in over the image. When they stop hovering over the pic, the caption fades out. What I tried to do, is add the following HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="assets/img/port1.jpg" class="porthome">
    <div class="cap">
        <h1>Compulite</h1>
        <p> Lorem Ipsum </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the '.cap' class:

```
.cap {
    background: rgba(58, 197, 167, 0.8);
    height: 262px;
    width: 262px;
    position: relative;
    top: -285px;
    left: 3px;
    display: none;
}
```

So the cap class isn't being displayed, and on hover, I want it to fade in:

```
    $(".porthome").hover(function() {
        $(this).next(".cap").fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $(this).next(".cap").fadeOut("slow");   
    });
```

Now the problem is: when I hover over one of the images, the cap fades in, fades out, fades in again till I hover out.

How is this possible? Is it a jQuery bug? Did I mess up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind this flickering, is that the 'hover' state ends because you create an element in front of it. Now you're hovering the `.cap` element.

To solve this, you can use the 'hover' state of the parent div. Since this is the parent, you will also be hovering this if the cursor is above either of the child elements.

So your HTML will look like this

```
<div class="col-md-3 cap-parent">
    <img src="assets/img/port1.jpg" class="porthome">
    <div class="cap">
        <h1>Compulite</h1>
        <p> Lorem Ipsum </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".cap-parent").hover(function() {
    $(this).children().next(".cap").fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
    $(this).children().next(".cap").fadeOut("slow");   
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6phcq6vj/

Note: the example doesn't work well since this div is full width. It should work better in the context of a bootstrap page.